# Pandas DataFrame custom agg function strange behavior float and int

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, aggregate

I am experiencing a strange behavior of Pandas aggregation with custom functions. The issue I have is similar to the one from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66911819/pandas-dataframe-custom-agg-function-strange-behavior), however I am facing a problem which produces a different result for integer and for float numbers which is very weird. Consider the following MWE:

```py
import pandas
import numpy

def my_average(x):
    return numpy.nanmean(x, axis=0)

def my_std(x):
    return numpy.nanstd(x, axis=0)

using_int = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
        'b': [3,4,5,6,7,8],
        'c': [1,1,3,3,4,4],
    }
).set_index('c')

using_float = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [1.3,2,3,4,5,6],
        'b': [3,4.4,5,6,7,8],
        'c': [1,1,3,3,4,4],
    }
).set_index('c')

for df in [using_int, using_float]:
    print(df)
    print(df.dtypes)
    print(df.agg([numpy.nanmean, numpy.nanstd]))
    print(df.agg([my_average, my_std]))
    print('-------')
```

which prints (Python 3.8.10, Numpy 1.22.1, Pandas 1.3.5)

```
   a  b
c      
1  1  3
1  2  4
3  3  5
3  4  6
4  5  7
4  6  8
a    int64
b    int64
dtype: object
                a         b
nanmean  3.500000  5.500000
nanstd   1.870829  1.870829
                   a         b
my_average  3.500000  5.500000
my_std      1.707825  1.707825
-------
     a    b
c          
1  1.3  3.0
1  2.0  4.4
3  3.0  5.0
3  4.0  6.0
4  5.0  7.0
4  6.0  8.0
a    float64
b    float64
dtype: object
                a         b
nanmean  3.550000  5.566667
nanstd   1.793042  1.812917
           a                 b       
  my_average my_std my_average my_std
c                                    
1        1.3    0.0        3.0    0.0
1        2.0    0.0        4.4    0.0
3        3.0    0.0        5.0    0.0
3        4.0    0.0        6.0    0.0
4        5.0    0.0        7.0    0.0
4        6.0    0.0        8.0    0.0
-------
```

As seen, the results for `df.agg([numpy.mean, numpy.std])` is always correct and what we would expect. However, when I want to use my custom functions it fails when the data type is floats. Why? How to solve this? Also, why is the result using `numpy.std` different from `my_std` even when using ints?

Comment: I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676250/pandas-agg-function-gives-different-results-for-numpy-std-vs-nanstd/47699378#47699378 or https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13344 might help